# Extending libvirt by adding a function for running a command remotely

Tags: c++, linux, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I have implemented a function in a remote driver in libvirt.

I run the command like this:

```
virCommandPtr cmd = NULL;
cmd=virCommandNewArgList("touch","/tmp/try.txt",NULL);
   if (virCommandRun(cmd, NULL) < 0)
       goto cleanup;
cleanup:
  virCommandFree(cmd);
  return 0;
```

When I execute this code snippet, it runs the `touch` command on the same host from which I call this function. It does not depend on the connection pointer.

I want to know how I can run a command on the host to which I establish a connection. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to fix some formatting and grammatical mistakes. I hope I haven't changed the meaning of what you were trying to ask; if so, feel free to re-edit. In particular, the title didn't appear to match the question; in the question, you asked about running a command remotely, but in the title, you said "locally".